# Optional long parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value

Tags: java, spring

I have two methods in my Spring controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = CARD_PATH)
    public @ResponseBody List<BaseballCard> getAllCards()

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = CARD_PATH + "/{id}")
    public BaseballCard getCard(@PathVariable("id") long id)
```

I get the following error when issuing a HTTP request for `GET /bbct/api/v1.0/card/1`.

> Optional long parameter 'id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type.

The suggestion is to declare `id` as a `Long`; however, I'd prefer to not do this.

I wonder why Spring thinks the `id` parameter is optional? Since I have a another method which processes requests when the id is missing, the id was certainly supplied, if the request is dispatched to `getCard()`.

Here is the full controller:

```
@Controller
public class BaseballCardController {

    private static final String CARD_PATH = "/bbct/api/v1.0/card";

    private List<BaseballCard> cards = new ArrayList<BaseballCard>();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = CARD_PATH)
    public @ResponseBody
    BaseballCard addCard(@RequestBody BaseballCard card) {
        cards.add(card);
        card.setId(cards.size());
        return card;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = CARD_PATH)
    public @ResponseBody List<BaseballCard> getAllCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = CARD_PATH + "/{id}")
    public BaseballCard getCard(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return cards.get((int)(id - 1));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you turn on INFO level logging on org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping and post what URLs are mapped when spring context initialized

Comment: @gerrytan I restarted my web app and now it doesn't give that error any more. Perhaps I was just running an old version of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happened was you (inadvertently?) made request to `/bbct/api/v1.0/card/` (pay attention to the trailing slash at the end) and it gets mapped into `getCard()` instead of `getAllCards()`

Probably it's a good idea to map the id into `Long` and set the `required = false` attribute on `@PathVariable("id")`, then do a redirect into `getAllCards()`. This way you can map both slash-suffixed and non-slash-suffixed version of `getAllCards()`

Comment: Both `/bbct/api/v1.0/card/` and `/bbct/api/v1.0/card` give me the list of cards without an error. I only get the error when I add an id (e.g. `/bbct/api/v1.0/card/1`).

Comment: And [`@PathVariable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) doesn't have a `required` method.